# FFmpeg Preserving Subtitles with Batch Trim

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to trim a bunch of videos, and the script below works, but it doesn't preserve the subtitles. Is there a way t keep the subtitles?

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal
Set "ext=mkv"
Set "opts=-v quiet"
Set "opts=%opts% -print_format "compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv""
Set "opts=%opts% -show_entries "format=duration""
If Exist *.%ext% (If Not Exist "Trimmed\" MD Trimmed)
For %%a In (*.%ext%) Do Call :Sub "%%~a"
Exit/B

:Sub
For /f "Tokens=1* Delims=." %%a In (
    'C:\ffmpeg\bin\FFProbe %opts% %1') Do (Set/A "ws=%%a-8.25" & Set "ps=%%b")
rem If %ws% Lss 20 GoTo :EOF
Set/A hh=ws/(60*60), lo=ws%%(60*60), mm=lo/60, ss=lo%%60
If %hh% Lss 10 Set hh=0%hh%
If %mm% Lss 10 Set mm=0%mm%
If %ss% Lss 10 Set ss=0%ss%
C:\ffmpeg\bin\FFMpeg -i %1 -ss 00:01:54 -to %hh%:%mm%:%ss%.%ps:~,3% -c:v copy -c:a copy "Trimmed\%~1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `-c:v copy -c:a copy` to `-c copy` (to [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) all stream types instead of just video and audio) and add [`-map 0`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to include all streams instead of relying on the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior.